# Submit Predetermined File From User With HTML Form

Tags: html

I am trying to create an HTML form that submits a predetermined file upon the press of an input button. This file is not located on the machine running the html server, it is located on the end users machine. Idealy I would like a solution that is as light weight as possible.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, it's not possible for a form to submit a local file without having the user select the file.

Browsers don't allow javascript (or other scripting technologies) to access the local file system, because it's a security risk.